# How to pass useState to context actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-context

I am having a form where all the functionality is working fine independently, as per design purpose I got a task to have all the form onchanges and save the form functionality into context actions. As that form is used in many places so for common functionality we need to add the code in context actions.

Below is my existing form code snippet where I cannot share complete code:

```
 const { state, actionsCollection } = useContext(StateContext);
  const [cardholder, setcardholder] = useState(state.creditCard.cardholder);
  const [cardnumber, setcardnumber] = useState(state.creditCard.cardnumber);
 const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    cardholder: false,
    cardnumber: false
  });
  const onChange = (e) => {
   switch (e.target.name) {
       case "cardholder":
        setcardholder(e.target.value);
        var cardholderName = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00FF\s*$]{1,50}$/.test(e.target.value);
        if (e.target.value === "") {
          setcardholder(e.target.value);
        }
        if (cardholderName === true) {
          setcardholder(e.target.value);
          setErrors({ ...errors, cardholder: false });
        }
        break;
........ code continues

}
```

Here I need to move this onchange code to context action  onChangeCreditCardFields():

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    actionsCollection.booking.onChangeCreditCardFields()
}
```

onchange is triggering but getting errors as:

```
setErrors not defined 
setcardholder not defined .....
```

As I cannot define usestate in actions.

How to migrate my onchange code with this functionality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be you can add params as state actions into `actionsCollection.booking.onChangeCreditCardFields` like

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    actionsCollection.booking.onChangeCreditCardFields(e, setcardholder, setErrors)
}
```

And then modify your function declaration accordingly

```
const onChangeCreditCardFields = (e, setcardholder, setErrors) {
   //TODO: Your logic
}
```